# Which is a Good PDF ebook reader in windows phone

Tags: 8.0, apps, pdf

I read lots of books and i want to know whether there is any good ebook reader for windows phone. In my windows phone i have used pdf reader like adobe reader and pdf reader from microsoft. But both have advantages and disadvantages, for example adober reader we can read ebook from memory card but we can't bookmark the page we read. Because of this every time i have to start from initial page. PDF reader from microsoft allow bookmarking but it will not read pdf files from memory card. Can you suggest a good pdf reader (possibly freeware) which can be used for reading ebooks from memory card and also help for book marking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about an app recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Kindle reader will do what you want. You can email PDF files to your Kindle account and they'll appear in your reader.